# how to limit textarea and move from extarea to another

Tags: javascript, css, forms, textarea, wysiwyg

I'm building a 'WYSIWYG' and I have a little problem:

I have 2 text areas.

I would like to limit the amount of writing in the first one, and when I finish writing in it, automatically continue writing in the 2nd textarea.

Just like in 'Word' :

http://postimg.org/image/5cuoxf6c9/

I'm using   execCommand  so I don't want it to be depended on the font size/ blanks etc...

Comment: What's your code? Are you expecting that the people provide you with a full finished solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the maxlength attribute on a text area:

```
<textarea maxlength="number">
```

EDIT:

you could do something like this to also include enter characters

```
<textarea id="mytext" rows="4" cols="50" onkeyup="LimitCharacters(this);" >
</textarea>
<textarea id="mytext2" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
<script>
function LimitCharacters(textArea) {
    var chars = textArea.value.length;
    if (chars > 10) {
        var words = textArea.value.split(" ");
        var lastWord = words.pop();
        textArea.value = words.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("mytext2").focus();
        document.getElementById("mytext2").value = lastWord;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's almost there
I want that just like in Word, if I insert words in a full page, the last words on the page should go on to the next page

Comment: ok, i updated the answer and the fiddle. Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/fu17eys4/1/

Comment: thanks,
it's almost there, though it still has bugs.
the last word is not necessarily the last word I write, but the last word in the textarea.
Also, as much as I write more, more words should move to the next textarea.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this.
Check the number of lines everytime you type in the textarea.
If the number of line is upper than max line number, set the focus on the other textarea.

**I haven't tried it**

```
String.prototype.lines = function() { return this.split(/\r*\n/); }
String.prototype.lineCount = function() { return this.lines().length; }

var maxLineCount = ...;

$('#textarea1').bind('input propertychange', function(e)
{
    if((this).val().lineCount > x)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#textarea2').focus();
    }
});
```

**EDIT :** Another way is to use a plugin which extends your textarea while you type text in it. And set max height. Once max height is reached, focus on the other textarea

Comment: doesn't work.
And also I want that just like in word, if I insert words in a full page, the last words on the page should go on to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea id="firstTextArea" maxlength="100" />
<textarea id="secondTextArea" />
```

with this script:

```
<script>
    $("#firstTextArea").on("keypress", function(){
        if($("#firstTextArea").length == 100){
            $("#secondTextArea").focus();
        }
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Almost. The focus must be on secondTextarea

Comment: doesn't work.
And also I want that just like in word, if I insert words in a full page, the last words on the page should go on to the next page

Comment: do you even use jquery? I mean what doesn't work in this snippet?

Comment: it never gets to this loop:
   if($("#firstTextArea").length == 100)

and even if it did work, id wouldn't have the effect like in word:
when I insert text in a full page, the last words in the page should go to the next textarea. It's not necessarily 'focus'

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tested it and working fine. 
below is script
<script>
function autotab(current,to){
    if (current.getAttribute && 
      current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")) {
        to.focus() 
        }
}
</script>

here is HTML ... please dont miss form tag with name attr.
<form name="note">
<textarea name="phone0" size=200 onKeyup="autotab(this, document.note.phone1)" maxlength=10></textarea>
<textarea name="phone1" size=200 onKeyup="autotab(this, document.note.phone2)" maxlength=10></textarea>
<textarea name="phone2" size=200 maxlength=10></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: This is very good,
not quite what I meant for, yet.

You can still get the scroll bar on the side (if you write a letter in a row, for ex.)
You can't add characters after the writing is complete in one of the textareas, you should be able to do so, and by doing so, the last word in the textarea will be pushed to the next textarea.